# в object persons {youth: i} место i написать сколько человек нашли

Tags: javascript

```
let persons = {};
let voters = [
    {name:'Bob' , age: 30, voted: true},
    {name:'Jake' , age: 32, voted: true},
    {name:'Kate' , age: 25, voted: false},
    {name:'Sam' , age: 20, voted: false},
    {name:'Phil' , age: 21, voted: true},
    {name:'Ed' , age:55, voted:true},
    {name:'Tami' , age: 54, voted:true},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 31, voted: false},
    {name: 'Becky', age: 43, voted: false},
    {name: 'Joey', age: 41, voted: true},
    {name: 'Jeff', age: 30, voted: true},
    {name: 'Zack', age: 19, voted: false}
];
for(let users of voters) {
    if (users.age > 18 && users.age < 35 && users.voted === true) {
         
    }
  }
```

Comment: и что вам мешает в ифе делать `persons.youth++` ?

Comment: или без ифа `p.youth += u.age > 18 && ...`

Comment: надо найти index

Comment: в вашем вопросе написано "сколько человек", про индекс там ничего не сказано.

Comment: да сколько человек получается 4 человек

Comment: надо так сделать чтоб получилось  persons { yout: 4}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно?

```js
let persons = {};
let voters = [
    {name:'Bob' , age: 30, voted: true},
    {name:'Jake' , age: 32, voted: true},
    {name:'Kate' , age: 25, voted: false},
    {name:'Sam' , age: 20, voted: false},
    {name:'Phil' , age: 21, voted: true},
    {name:'Ed' , age:55, voted:true},
    {name:'Tami' , age: 54, voted:true},
    {name: 'Mary', age: 31, voted: false},
    {name: 'Becky', age: 43, voted: false},
    {name: 'Joey', age: 41, voted: true},
    {name: 'Jeff', age: 30, voted: true},
    {name: 'Zack', age: 19, voted: false}
];

let filtered = voters.filter(user => users.age > 18 && users.age < 35 && users.voted === true);
persons.youth = filtered.length;
```

Comment: спасибо родной .......я users.length   сделал по этому не получилось

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, нажмите стрелочку вверх, если ответ решает вашу проблему - галочку.